# Pymongo: collection.find_one() returns dictionary object instead of document

Tags: python, database, mongodb, dictionary, pymongo

I started setting up a MongoDB and communicate with it via Python / Pymongo.
But I came across this problem:

code:

```
my_dict = {"key1": "value1", "key2", "value2"}
my_collection.insert_one(my_dict)
doc = my_collection.find_one({"key1": "value1"})
print(doc)
```

output:

```
{'_id': ObjectId('5a5c2c2b44cdc53e8417825e'), 'key1': 'value1', 'key2': 'value2'}
```

The same happens without arguments.
This function is supposed to return a single document, so what's wrong?

Thanks for your answers.
Greetings, Nils

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue in your case is you are inserting single document.

```
my_dict = {"key1": "value1", "key2", "value2"}
```

This is a single document. If you want it to be treated as two separate documents. You should try this :

```
my_dict = [{"key1": "value1"},{"key2", "value2"}]
```

You can refer the pymongo  [documentation](http://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tutorial.html) for more details.

Comment: Thanks a lot Rajat Mishra.